# Multiple url redirect using .htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I am having one website and it is redirecting to five different index file randomly using php.

- www.xyzdomain.com/index.php
- www.xyzdomain.com/index2.php
- www.xyzdomain.com/index3.php
- www.xyzdomain.com/index4.php
- www.xyzdomain.com/index5.php

I want to redirect it using **.htaccess** , the same way it redirecting php.

I found that using htaccess we can redirect urls like,

```
Redirect 301 / http://www.xyzdomain.com/index.php
```

or

```
Redirect 302 / http://www.xyzdomain.com/index.php
```

Currently i am doing that with using **php** random array.

```
<?php

$urls = array("index.php",
              "index2.php",
              "index3.php",
              "index4.php",
              "index5.php");
$url = $urls[array_rand($urls)];
header("Location: http://www.xyzdomain.com/$url");
?>
```

**Question**: How to redirect multiple index randomly using .htaccess rules?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not fully random like PHP code but you can achieve something similar using `mod_rewrite` using `TIME_SEC` variable that represents seconds value of the current time. Consider this code:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# dont rewrite more than once
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} .+
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

# redirect all requests for php file to index file if %{TIME_SEC} is 0, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50
# or if %{TIME_SEC} is 1, 11, 21, 31, 41, 51
RewriteCond %{TIME_SEC} [01]$
RewriteRule ^.+?\.php$ index.php [L,NC]

# redirect all requests for php file to index file if %{TIME_SEC} is 2, 12, 22, 32, 42, 52
# or if %{TIME_SEC} is 3, 13, 23, 33, 43, 53
RewriteCond %{TIME_SEC} [23]$
RewriteRule ^.+?\.php$ index2.php [L,NC]

# redirect all requests for php file to index file if %{TIME_SEC} is 4, 14, 24, 34, 44, 54
# or if %{TIME_SEC} is 5, 15, 25, 35, 45, 55
RewriteCond %{TIME_SEC} [45]$
RewriteRule ^.+?\.php$ index3.php [L,NC]

# redirect all requests for php file to index file if %{TIME_SEC} is 6, 16, 26, 36, 46, 56
# or if %{TIME_SEC} is 7, 17, 27, 37, 47, 57
RewriteCond %{TIME_SEC} [67]$
RewriteRule ^.+?\.php$ index4.php [L,NC]

# redirect all requests for php file to index file if %{TIME_SEC} is ending in 8, 9
RewriteCond %{TIME_SEC} [89]$
RewriteRule ^.+?\.php$ index5.php [L,NC]
```

Comment: thank you Anubhava. i was expecting your answer! and referring your previous answers!I will try this, can you please explain a brief about this method? How it works?

Comment: As I mentioned above that `TIME_SEC` variable represents seconds value of the current time. So based on seconds value above rules will route the requests to different index files. If time is `14:33:00` or `14:33:01` then it routes to `/index.php`. If time is `14:33:02` or `14:33:03` then it routes to `/index1.php` and so on to other index files based on current seconds value.

Comment: You can use `RewriteCond %{TIME_SEC} <= 12` and 24, 36, 48. Like that it's approximately the same time for the last one. And it's a lot easier, if you have to change the number of pages.

Comment: Yes it can be done that way also by dividing in equal intervals.

Comment: Thank you Anubhava! It is working fine! There is one question! I think .htaccess redirect method is much faster than php method! Isnt it? If yes explain in brief please!

Comment: Yes using `mod_rewrite` is definitely faster that doing it in PHP because Apache needs to load & invoke PHP module and then PHP code needs to be interpreted and executed. Which is going to be much slower than `mod_rewrite` rules.

Answer (score 1):

To redirect individual files, like example.com/oldfile.htm to newfile.htm you can use a 301 redirect like this: http://www.inmotionhosting.com/support/website/redirects/setting-up-a-301-permanent-redirect-via-htaccess